# What should I test here?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have method, that delete entity from DB by ID :

```
public void delete(Integer id)  {
    try {
        connection = getNewConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.warning("connection error");
    }
    PreparedStatement ps = getPreparedStatement(DELETE_SMTH);
    try {
        ps.setInt(ID, id);
        ps.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.warning("error with statements");
    } finally {
        closeStatement(ps);
        closeConnection();
    }
}
```

Now I try to create unit-test, using mockito and TestNg.

```
@Test
public void testDelete() throws SQLException {
    Connection connectionMock = Mockito.mock(Connection.class);
    PreparedStatement preparedStatementMock = Mockito.mock(PreparedStatement.class);
    myDAO DAO = Mockito.mock(myDAO.class);
    Mockito.when(DAO.getNewConnection()).thenReturn(connectionMock);
    Mockito.when(DAO.getPreparedStatement(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(preparedStatementMock);
}
```

Am I on a right way?
How can I finish this test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define all mocks
2. Call instance.delete(id)
3. Check the needed methods were executed by "Mockito.verify"

In your case I would suggest check following methods were executed:
        setInt(ID, id)
        execute()
        closeStatement(ps)
        closeConnection()

Comment: Should I mock myDAO(instance)?

Comment: If you mock instance you cannot run real execution of delete. Consider spy in this case. This is ability to do partial mock of instance where you can call real and mocked methods.